# Spring Security 3.0 on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-security

Blogs show that Spring Security works on Google App Engine, but based on the date of their posts, I think they are speaking of version 2 of Spring Security.

Has anyone tried Spring Security 3 on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I just tried it and Spring Security 3.0 works fine on the Google App Engine