# How it works? Google app engine + Spring

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, multithreading

I wonder how spring and google app engine work together

I know that [google app engine cannot run threads.](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html)
I think spring is working with threads.
(if i'm wrong, please correct)
So how [spring and google app engine work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126263/spring-security-3-0-on-google-app-engine) together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Spring Framework in Google App Engine and it worked just fine. So its not using threads to atleast to controllers etc. normal web application stuff. Most likely Spring cron tasks use threads, so instead of those you most likely have to use App Engines own cron task service.

Answer (score 1):

According to the "[Will it play](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine)" of GAE, Spring MVC is supported.  I'm not sure if this is what you mean.  I have tried running Grails application (which is built on top of Spring) on GAE and it works fine.  If you are creating your application from scratch, be sure to read the issues related to Spring and related framework addons like the Spring Security and Spring ORM, and some customization you need to perform or additional coding for Google's storage system.  Check out their [group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Manny;

I know spring is supported but I wan to know how? 

What is the mechanism behind? How it works? Because Google app engine does not support threads and spring working with threads at least this is what i know.
Am I clear now?